# Does the coming of menses break the fast?

Tags: sharia, sawm, women, menses

Of course, menses go for few days and woman cannot fast anymore with such condition.

So what does the Quran and the hadith has to say about it? What should woman do then?

Answer (score 6):

The woman should break the fast and make all the missed ones up after Ramadhan :)

> Mu`âdhah, the daughter of`Abd Allah al-`Adwiyyah, asked`Aisha:
>   "Why do we make up our fasts but not our prayers?
>
> `Aisha answered: "When we were beset with menstruation, we were
>   commanded to to make up our fasts but not our prayers."

This is an authentic hadîth reported in Sahîh al-Bukhârî (321) and Sahîh Muslim (335).

Comment: Since when A'ishah is an authority? I'm not doubting that A'ishah is a believing pious woman, but shouldn't Muhammad be the one who answers these questions rather than A'ishah?

Comment: We have to remember that all of the Sahabas and Sahabis are the next best thing to Nabi SAW as they were present when he spoke. Many questions arose after Nabi SAW passed away therefore the Sahabas were asked.